# How to pass an RDS object to the stackoverflow community

Tags: r

Suppose I want to ask a question about a code that uses an **rds** object containing a lot of information.
For example, [here](http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/rds/ITA_adm0.rds) you can download such an object (named "`ITA_adm1.rds`").
Locally I'll do:

```
...
italia <- readRDS("ITA_adm1.rds")
...
```

Now, suppose I want "pass" you this object (such to let you try it). I have tried to solve throught dput():

```
objX <- dput(x = italia, file = "")
italia2 <- dget(objX)
```

but it doesn't work because `objX` is `null`.

How can I put it at your disposal (supposing it isn't on the web)?

EDIT:
the final purpose (if it could be useful) is to plot a map

```
> col1 <- dput(col)
c("#FFFF80FF", "#FFFF00FF", "#FFAA00FF", "#FF5500FF", "#FF0000FF")
> library(sp)
> spplot(italia, "Feature", col.regions=col, main = Title)
```

and to ask you how to change the side legend.

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't do that (and it might not even be allowed), as serialized data is (1) not as portable as plain text data, and (2) possibly a security risk.

Comment: Usually you would just post a a small representative sample of your data, just enough so others should be able to answer your question.

Comment: In general is what I do. Nevertheless, in this case, I need to plot a map (I guess you have already understood the country I'm talking about) and I can do it only if I have the rds object of the link. So the only way is you to have it.